# Concise Java Code: assignment, null check and conditional execution

Tags: java

The following Java code appears to be fairly lengthy and somewhat repetitive. Can it be made more concise?

```
A myObjA = getObject(id, A.class);

if (myObjA != null) {
  handleA(myObjA);
}

B myObjB = getObject(id, B.class);

if (myObjB != null) {
  handleB(myObjB);
}

C myObjC = getObject(id, C.class);

if (myObjC != null) {
  handleC(myObjC);
}
```

Forgot to mention. This is not running on Java 8 :(

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refining the other answers:

```
Optional.ofNullable(getObject(id, A.class)).ifPresent(this::handleA);
Optional.ofNullable(getObject(id, B.class)).ifPresent(this::handleB);
Optional.ofNullable(getObject(id, C.class)).ifPresent(this::handleC);
```

This is shorter and more concise.

Comment: Oooo I like this one more than my answer. Well done!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that we aren't working on Java 8 yet

Comment: Sadly pre Java 8 there is no nice way to handle this (unless leveraging Polymorphism and Inheritance)

Answer (score 3):

Sure, thanks to the magic of java-8! Simply create this helper method:

```
private <T> static void getAndHandleIfNonNull(int id, Class<T> clazz, Consumer<T> handler) {
    T t = getObject(id, clazz);
    if (t != null) {
        handler.accept(t);
    }
}
```

And then call it:

```
getAndHandleIfNonNull(id, A.class, this::handleA);
getAndHandleIfNonNull(id, B.class, this::handleB);
getAndHandleIfNonNull(id, C.class, this::handleC);
```

Comment: Beat me to it!!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that we aren't working on Java 8 yet

Answer (score 1):

How about making use of the new Java 8 features?

```
Optional.ofNullable(getObject(id,A.class)).ifPresent(myObjA -> handleA(myObjA));
Optional.ofNullable(getObject(id,B.class)).ifPresent(myObjB -> handleB(myObjB));
Optional.ofNullable(getObject(id,C.class)).ifPresent(myObjC -> handleC(myObjC));
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that we aren't working on Java 8 yet

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can put a null check fence in your handleX methods, your code becomes much more concise.

```
handleA(getObject(id, A.class));
handleB(getObject(id, B.class));
handleC(getObject(id, C.class));
```